# What is the algebraic structure of higher-order jet spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, jet-bundles

Firstly excuse any sloppiness here -- I'm not a mathematician by training so I've had a difficult time formalizing my question and tracking down relevant material.

Consider a point in a smooth manifold, $p \in M$.  Linear approximations to functions passing through that point span the first-order jet space, $J_p$ which can be interpreted as linear maps over the tangent space at that point, $T_p M$.  Compositions of these functions manifests in a straightforward compositional algebra of jets where in local coordinates the corresponding Jacobians are multiplied together.

Multiplying a compositional Jacobian by an element of the tangent space gives directional derivatives.  This action is exactly the action of *first order forward mode automatic differentiation*.  We can also take the adjoint of this compositional Jacobian and multiply it by an element of the cotangent space to give gradients.  This is similarly the action of *first order reverse mode automatic differentiation*.  Everything at first order is wonderful.

My question concerns what happens for higher-order approximations to functions and the compositional structure of the corresponding higher-order jets.

At higher-orders the partial derivatives of each order will in general mix whenever two jets are composed together, and then this composite object acts on a direct product of higher-order tangent bundles.  For example, at second-order the composite map eats two elements of the first-order tangent space, $u_1, u_2 \in T_p M$ and one element of $v \in T^{2}_p M$ and returns two first-order directional derivatives, $J \cdot u_1$ and $J \cdot u_2$, and one second-order directional derivative, $u_1^{T} \cdot H \cdot u_2 + J v$, where $H$ is the Hessian.  There is clearly some interesting structure here where the image of the second-order jets seems to decompose into $T_p M \otimes T_p M \otimes T^{2}_p M$ but my math isn't good enough to work out the general theory or find the right references.  *Does anyone know what kind of algebraic structure is at work here, either for the jets or the action of the jets, or can suggest appropriate references?*

The immediate follow up is then how does this structure admit adjoints?  If the above gives higher-order forward mode automatic differentiation, how would we be able to take the adjoint of various subspaces of jets (or jet tangent products) to enable higher-order reverse mode automatic differentiation?

Using higher-order dual numbers I worked out the second and third-order behavior heuristically in Chapter 1 of https://github.com/stan-dev/nomad/tree/master/manual (again please excuse the mathematical sloppiness or poor notation) but I would love to have a better geometric/algebraic structure of what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After fixing a coordinate system, $k$-jets can be identified with (tuples 
 of) polynomials of degree $k$ - the $k$-jet of $f$ is represented by the $k$-th order Taylor polynomials of $f$.  The composition of $k$-jets is simply the composition of the corresponding polynomials mod $(X^i)^{k+1},$ i.e. $(P \circ Q)(X)$ is just $P(Q(X))$ truncated to order $|X|^k.$

As an example, suppose we want to differentiate a composition $M \overset{f}\to M\overset \phi \to\mathbb R$ at a fixed point of $f$. The chain and product rules tells us we should end up with 
\begin{align}
\partial_i(\phi \circ f) &=\partial_k \phi\,\partial_i f^k, \\
\partial_i \partial_j(\phi \circ f)&=\partial_k \phi\,\partial_i\partial_jf^k+ \partial_k \partial_l \phi\,\partial_if ^k\,\partial_jf^l.
\end{align} (I'm using the Einstein summation convention.)
The second-order Taylor polynomials of these two maps give us the coordinate representatives of their 2-jets:
\begin{align}P(X)=j^2\phi(X) &= \phi_0 + \partial_k \phi \, X^k+\frac 1 2 \partial_k \partial_l \phi\,X^kX^l,\\
Q(X)=j^2 f(X)^k &= \partial_i f^k\,X^i+\frac 1 2 \partial_i \partial_j f^k\,X^iX^j.
\end{align}

Now we can just substitute $Q$ into $P$, yielding 
\begin{multline}P(Q(X)) = \phi_0 +  \partial_k \phi\,(\partial_i f^k X^i+\frac 1 2 \partial_i \partial_j f^k X^i X^j)\\ + \frac 1 2\partial_k \partial_l \phi\,(\partial_i f^k X^i+\frac 1 2 \partial_i \partial_j f^k X^i X^j)(\partial_a f^l X^a+\frac 1 2 \partial_a \partial_b f^l X^a X^b).
\end{multline}
Expanding, truncating to order $|X|^2$ and collecting coefficients of $X^i$ we find $$ j^2(\phi \circ f)(X)=\phi_0 + \partial_k \phi\, \partial_i f^k\,X^i + \frac12(\partial_k \phi\,\partial_i\partial_jf^k + \partial_k\partial_l\phi\,\partial_i f^k \partial_j f^l)X^iX^j.$$ Reading off the coefficients of this Taylor polynomial we see that we have arrived at the correct answer.

This "truncated polynomial algebra" is a little weird - there's no easy law to expand the  composition $P\circ(Q+R),$ so it's not a ring or anything quite so nice. (Indeed, in the context of general manifolds, addition/multiplication of these polynomials does not translate to any meaningful operation on jets.) I've only ever seen it studied in the context of jets/Taylor polynomials. Lots of people care about jets, though, so there is no shortage of reading material! For a comprehensive reference, see section 12 (and maybe 13) of the freely available book [Natural Operations in Differential Geometry](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf).

You're right that we can represent any jet space by tensors: for example we have \begin{align}J^2_p(M,N)_q &\simeq L(T_pM,T_qN) \oplus L(\mathrm{Sym}^2(T_p M),T_qN) \\
&\subset (T_p M^* \otimes T_q N)\oplus(T_pM^* \otimes T_pM^* \otimes T_qN).\end{align}
Of course, this identification obscures the composition structure and is coordinate-dependent, so while it's certainly useful to know, it's often more productive to be thinking about polynomials. (The polynomial representation is also coordinate-dependent, of course; but you can get a precise understanding of how they transform using jet groups.)

Regarding adjoints, I'm unsure exactly what you want - perhaps if you explain what you're looking for more thoroughly I could point you in the right direction. The relationship between velocities and covelocities is not so simple at higher order - when $k>1$ the spaces $J^k(\mathbb R,M)$ and $J^k(M, \mathbb R)$ do not even have the same dimension, so there's no direct analog of the isomorphism $$J^1_0(\mathbb R, M)=TM \simeq T^*M = J^1(M,\mathbb R)_0.$$

Comment: I'm with you all through the kth-order jet spaces having the algebraic structure of R[z] / z^{k + 1}.  This is also how I worked out the second and third-order results heuristically, using higher-order dual numbers to implement the truncation.  But where did you get the identification of $J^{2}_p(M, N)$ with tensors?  I have to admit that I did attempt to get through Kolar et al last year with limited success -- any pointers to relevant material is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Regarding adjoints, I know we lose the isomorphism at higher-orders but there seems to be some notion of invariant subspaces.  For example, if you hit a higher-order jet with the right combination of elements of $T_p M$, $T^{2}_p M$, etc then you get linear maps that can be transposed to define operations on the various order cotangent spaces.